# Android Insert Statement

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sqlite, insert

I have create an android application where in users can add, update, and delete stuffs from the database

In my DataSource java file i have this code:

```
public void addWebsite(String sitename, String username, String password) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_URL, sitename);
        values.put(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_USERNAME, username);
        values.put(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_PASSWORD, password);
        database.insert(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_URL, null,values);
    }
```

the above code makes the insert statement.

```
public void updateWebsite(WebsiteRecords website){
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_URL, website.getSitename());
        values.put(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_USERNAME, website.getUsername());
        values.put(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_PASSWORD, website.getPassword());
        database.update(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_URL, values, MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ID  + " = " + website.getId(), null);
    }
```

the above code displays an update statement

```
public void deleteWebsite(WebsiteRecords website) {
        database.delete(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_URL, MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ID  + " = " + website.getId(), null);
    }
```

and lastly, the above code is for the delete statement.

My problem is, I get this username from my login, and from that I want to add, update and delete stuffs which has the username i got from my login screen. I was thinking of making

```
Cursor mCursor = database.rawQuery("INSERT INTO " + TABLE_URL + " VALUES('" + sitename + "', '" + username + "', '" + password + "') " WHERE loginname=?", new String [] {loginname});
```

or anything like that but I am scared that it won't work. Same goes with the update and delete. It will only add, update, delete, view files which has a loginname of for instance "iamcoolin3d".

Anyone can help me with this?

Comment: `I am scared that it won't work.` -> Without even trying first?

Comment: I tried already. Just run it and when I clicked on the log in button, the emulator shows me "Unfortunately My Accounts has stopped working". and based on my logcat I got this errors in my datasource file

Answer (score 0):

The line:

```
Cursor mCursor = database.rawQuery("INSERT INTO " + TABLE_URL + " VALUES('" + sitename + "', '" + username + "', '" + password + "') " WHERE loginname=?", new String [] {loginname});
```

Should be:

```
Cursor mCursor = database.rawQuery("INSERT INTO " + TABLE_URL + " VALUES('" + sitename + "', '" + username + "', '" + password + "')  WHERE loginname=?", new String [] {loginname});
```

there is an extra **`"`** before `WHERE`

Comment: i get an error in TABLE_URL. it seems that my table name cannot be detected by the datasource. since my table name is in another java file which is MySQLiteHelper java file.

Comment: replace it with MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_URL

Comment: how about the edit and delete statements? how to make them like the insert command based on my codes

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with your last line, you must put WHERE in the String, otherwise it won't work.